# Spring Boot - Test Transaction Inconsistence on Hibernate 4.3.x.Final vs 5.0.x.Final

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-test

I've been finding an inconsistence on spring-boot transaction test result when using hibernate 4.3.x.Final (Which is version shipped with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as transitive dependency) against 5.0.x.Final version, first one always pass and the 5 version always fail (according to attached sources). Can anyone here elaborate, what (spring boot/hibernate) settings must be configured to anticipate this issue.

Here are my pom.xml for sample project to reproduce errors

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>id.tomatech.learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test-issue</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!--hibernate.version>5.0.7.Final</hibernate.version-->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Spring Boot main class

```
package id.tomatech.learn;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestIssueApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestIssueApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Sample JPA entity

```
package id.tomatech.learn.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Spring data jpa repository

```
package id.tomatech.learn.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import id.tomatech.learn.entity.Person;

@Repository
public interface PersonRespository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

Controller

```
package id.tomatech.learn.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import id.tomatech.learn.entity.Person;
import id.tomatech.learn.repository.PersonRespository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/people")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRespository people;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<Person> register(@Validated @RequestBody Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Person>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        Person registeredPerson = people.save(person);
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(registeredPerson, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And controller test.

```
package id.tomatech.learn.controller;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestTransaction;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.jdbc.JdbcTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import id.tomatech.learn.TestIssueApplication;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=TestIssueApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class PeopleControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(applicationContext)
                .alwaysDo(print())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRegisterPerson_withValidJsonRequestPayload_okAndJsonResponsePayload() throws Exception {
        String payload = "{\"name\": \"Zaky Alvan\"}";
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = post("/people").content(payload).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

        int countBefore = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "person");
        mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(instanceOf(Number.class))))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(equalTo("Zaky Alvan"))));

        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        int countAfter = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "person");

        assertThat(countAfter, is(equalTo(countBefore+1)));

        TestTransaction.flagForRollback();
    }
}
```

Running with following content of `application.properties`

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

Here are relevant log snippet when using hibernate 5.0.x.Final

```
2016-02-18 22:22:36.968 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL query [SELECT COUNT(0) FROM person]
2016-02-18 22:22:37.139 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.m.d.ConstraintDescriptorImpl     : Adding composing constraint: ConstraintDescriptorImpl{annotation=javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, payloads=[], hasComposingConstraints=true, isReportAsSingleInvalidConstraint=false, elementType=FIELD, definedOn=DEFINED_LOCALLY, groups=[interface javax.validation.groups.Default], attributes={message={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}, groups=[Ljava.lang.Class;@6ef1c3f7, payload=[Ljava.lang.Class;@3386c206}, constraintType=GENERIC}.
2016-02-18 22:22:37.177 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
2016-02-18 22:22:37.191 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure        : Sequence value obtained: 1
2016-02-18 22:22:37.191 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
2016-02-18 22:22:37.192 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: 1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /people
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

Handler:
             Type = id.tomatech.learn.controller.PersonController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<id.tomatech.learn.entity.Person> id.tomatech.learn.controller.PersonController.register(id.tomatech.learn.entity.Person,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"id":1,"name":"Zaky Alvan"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2016-02-18 22:22:37.393 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL query [SELECT COUNT(0) FROM person]
2016-02-18 22:22:37.395 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2016-02-18 22:22:37.396 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2016-02-18 22:22:37.397 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2016-02-18 22:22:37.399 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2016-02-18 22:22:37.399 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2016-02-18 22:22:37.401 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
2016-02-18 22:22:37.401 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : id.tomatech.learn.entity.Person{name=Zaky Alvan, id=1}
2016-02-18 22:22:37.423 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into person (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person (name, id) values (?, ?)
2016-02-18 22:22:37.430 DEBUG 1299 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
2016-02-18 22:22:37.432  INFO 1299 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Committed transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@26aa12dd testClass = PeopleControllerTest, testInstance = id.tomatech.learn.controller.PeopleControllerTest@1a785fd5, testMethod = testRegisterPerson_withValidJsonRequestPayload_okAndJsonResponsePayload@PeopleControllerTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <1>
     but: was <0>, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3fd7a715 testClass = PeopleControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class id.tomatech.learn.TestIssueApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
2016-02-18 22:22:37.448  INFO 1299 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@7e0b85f9: startup date [Thu Feb 18 22:22:30 WIB 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-02-18 22:22:37.471  INFO 1299 --- [       Thread-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-02-18 22:22:37.472 DEBUG 1299 --- [       Thread-1] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000031: Closing
```

Relevant log snipped when using hibernate 4.3.x.Final (Transitive dependency of spring-boot's spring-boot-starter-data-jpa)

```
2016-02-18 22:27:47.148 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL query [SELECT COUNT(0) FROM person]
2016-02-18 22:27:47.320 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.m.d.ConstraintDescriptorImpl     : Adding composing constraint: ConstraintDescriptorImpl{annotation=javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, payloads=[], hasComposingConstraints=true, isReportAsSingleInvalidConstraint=false, elementType=FIELD, definedOn=DEFINED_LOCALLY, groups=[interface javax.validation.groups.Default], attributes={message={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}, groups=[Ljava.lang.Class;@305552d6, payload=[Ljava.lang.Class;@729cd862}, constraintType=GENERIC}.
2016-02-18 22:27:47.370 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Executing identity-insert immediately
2016-02-18 22:27:47.381 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into person (id, name) values (default, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person (id, name) values (default, ?)
2016-02-18 22:27:47.394 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper         : Natively generated identity: 1

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /people
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

Handler:
             Type = id.tomatech.learn.controller.PersonController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<id.tomatech.learn.entity.Person> id.tomatech.learn.controller.PersonController.register(id.tomatech.learn.entity.Person,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"id":1,"name":"Zaky Alvan"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2016-02-18 22:27:47.569 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL query [SELECT COUNT(0) FROM person]
2016-02-18 22:27:47.571 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl      : rolling back
2016-02-18 22:27:47.572 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : rolled JDBC Connection
2016-02-18 22:27:47.572 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : re-enabling autocommit
2016-02-18 22:27:47.573 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Releasing JDBC connection
2016-02-18 22:27:47.573 DEBUG 1316 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Released JDBC connection
2016-02-18 22:27:47.574  INFO 1316 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@26aa12dd testClass = PeopleControllerTest, testInstance = id.tomatech.learn.controller.PeopleControllerTest@3962ec84, testMethod = testRegisterPerson_withValidJsonRequestPayload_okAndJsonResponsePayload@PeopleControllerTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3fd7a715 testClass = PeopleControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class id.tomatech.learn.TestIssueApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
2016-02-18 22:27:47.578  INFO 1316 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@7e0b85f9: startup date [Thu Feb 18 22:27:39 WIB 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-02-18 22:27:47.591  INFO 1316 --- [       Thread-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-02-18 22:27:47.592 DEBUG 1316 --- [       Thread-1] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000031: Closing
```

Comment: If it fails, it would also give some errors. Where is the error log?

Comment: Updated my question with log snippets.

Comment: It seems transaction not committed immediately after call of `TestTransaction.flagForCommit();`. But have no idea how to fix this.